# Angular2 with webpack reports error 404 index.html not found

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Using Angular2  I started a project but when I open

```
http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/index.html
```

or

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html
```

it reports 404 index.html not found.

I have no idea why.

I'm using Windows. [The project is available on Github](https://github.com/ryvo/angular2-blogger.git).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your project has split your webpack configuration, it needs to merge those configurations to webpack understand all your parameters.

The simplest way is using _.merge method from lodash, see more at: https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#merge

First you install the lodash dependency:

```
npm install --save-dev lodash
```

Then you merge your configurations, your webpack.config.js should look like:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var helpers = require('./helpers');
var _ = require('lodash');
```

var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

```
module.exports = _.merge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map', // source-map
    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        //publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    }
});
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: This advice fixed my main issue. After configuration was fixed another problem appeared - wrong loader 'html'. When I changed it to 'raw' it started work. Many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, another advice that may help you is that your extract-text-webpack-plugin dependency is missing in you package.json file, to run your application I had to put this dependency "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1"